# Standard input and output units in Fortran 90?

Tags: fortran, stdout, stdin, stderr, fortran90

How can I read and write to the standard input, output and error streams `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` in Fortran? I've heard writing to `stderr`, for example, *used* to be `write(5, fmt=...)`, with `5` the unit for `stderr`, and I know the way to write to `stdout` is to use `write(*, fmt=...)`.

How do I read and write to the standard input and output units with the `ifort` compiler?

Compiler version:

> Intel(R) Fortran Compiler for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 10.0 Build 20070426 Package ID: l_fc_p_10.0.023 Copyright (C) 1985-2007 Intel Corporation. All rights reserved

Comment: Which version of ifort? They have F2003 support at least for versions 11.1 onward.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you have a Fortran 2003 compiler, the intrinsic module [`iso_fortran_env`](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/iso_fortran_env) defines the variables `input_unit`, `output_unit` and `error_unit` which point to standard in, standard out and standard error respectively.

I tend to use something like

```
#ifdef f2003
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only : stdin=>input_unit, &
                                          stdout=>output_unit, &
                                          stderr=>error_unit
#else
#define stdin  5
#define stdout 6
#define stderr 0
#endif
```

in my input/output routines. Although this of course means [preprocessing](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Preprocessors) your source file (to do this with `ifort`, use the `-fpp` flag when compiling your source code or change the source file extension from `.f` to `.F` or from `.f90` to `.F90`).

An alternative to this would be to write your own, non-intrinsic, `iso_fortran_env` module (if you don't have a Fortran 2003 compiler)<del>, as discussed [here](http://old.nabble.com/iso_fortran_env-td6041849.html)</del> (this link has died since this answer was posted). In this example they use a module:

```
module iso_fortran_env

  ! Nonintrinsic version for Lahey/Fujitsu Fortran for Linux. 
  ! See Subclause 13.8.2 of the Fortran 2003 standard. 

  implicit NONE 
  public 

  integer, parameter :: Character_Storage_Size = 8 
  integer, parameter :: Error_Unit = 0 
  integer, parameter :: File_Storage_Size = 8 
  integer, parameter :: Input_Unit = 5 
  integer, parameter :: IOSTAT_END = -1 
  integer, parameter :: IOSTAT_EOR = -2 
  integer, parameter :: Numeric_Storage_Size = 32 
  integer, parameter :: Output_Unit = 6 

end module iso_fortran_env
```

As noted in other answers, 0, 5 and 6 are *usually* `stderr`, `stdin` and `stdout` (this is true for `ifort` on Linux) but this is **not** defined by the Fortran standard. Using the `iso_fortran_env` module is the correct way to portably write to these units.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a 2003 compatible compiler; I'm in fortran 90.

Comment: @Pureferret So you can just use one of the alternative methods which I suggest. Also recent `ifort` versions support parts of the 2003 standard including `iso_fortran_env`.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work, the compiler said everything in your first block was 'bad preprocessor syntax' (I think)

I haven't tried your second block yet, but if @tpg2114's solution doesn't work, I'm not sure why/how your solution would work.

Comment: As I said in my answer you need to preprocess the file (the `#`'s are [preprocessor directives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)) and make sure that the #'s appear in the first column. With the intel compiler this mean using the `-fpp` flag when compiling your source files. The second example avoids having to do this, but you should check that the the values used match those of your compiler/machine.

Comment: Right. I had no idea what pre-processing was. It seems to work now.

Comment: @Pureferret Glad to hear it works. Pre-processing can be very useful, although I don't see it used in Fortran codes that often.

Comment: You can also change the extension of your file. If it is .F or .F90 instead of .f or .f90, then the compiler will pre-process it for you without an special flags.

Comment: I was trying this approach but isn't it `stdin=>input_unit` and so on ? Just for correction.

Comment: @bela83 Thanks for pointing that out. I have corrected my answer. I'm amazed that no one else has mentioned this before.

Comment: @Chris your link "preprocessing" has died. As it seems to be a fairly important part of the answer, please consider finding a new source to link to.

Comment: @Chris nobody mentioned it because nobody is using Fortran 2003 yet...?

Comment: @Juanlu001 I hope that isn't the case - this is 2015! I hope we don't have to wait the best part of a decade before a standard starts to become used. I was certainly using some 2003 features back in 2008, hopefully I'm not the only person.

Answer (score 17):

The Fortran standard doesn't specify which units numbers correspond to stdin/out/err. The usual convention, followed by e.g. gfortran, is that stderr=0, stdin=5, stdout=6.

If your compiler supports the F2003 ISO_FORTRAN_ENV intrinsic module, that module contains the constants INPUT_UNIT, OUTPUT_UNIT, and ERROR_UNIT allowing the programmer to portably retrieve the unit numbers for the preconnected units.

Answer (score 10):

It's actually 0 for stderr. 5 is stdin, 6 is stdout.

For example:

```
PROGRAM TEST
  WRITE(0,*) "Error"
  WRITE(6,*) "Good"
END PROGRAM TEST
```

Gives:

```
./a.out 
Error
Good
```

while

```
./a.out 2> /dev/null
Good
```

I would store a PARAMETER that is STDERR = 0 to make it portable, so if you hit a platform that is different you can just change the parameter.

This example was compiled and run with ifort 12.1.1.256, 11.1.069, 11.1.072 and 11.1.073.

Comment: I just tried it with 4 different versions of ifort and it works, and it also works with gfortran 4.6.0, 4.6.1 and 4.6.2. Can you post what errors it gives you?

Comment: It doesn't give me any errors using `write(0,*)` but when I re-direct stderr to file, nothing happens. The version is: Intel(R) Fortran Compiler for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 10.0    Build 20070426 Package ID: l_fc_p_10.0.023
Copyright (C) 1985-2007 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Comment: This is compiler specific. There is no guarantee in the Fortran 9 standard that those numbers be 0,5 and 6.

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to write to `stdout` in Fortran is to put an asterisk instead of the unit number, i.e.,

```
WRITE(*,fmt) something
```

or to simply use

```
PRINT fmt,something
```

Similarly, the standard way to read from `stdin` is

```
READ(*,fmt) something
```

There is no standard way to write to `stderr` unless you use `ERROR_UNIT` from the `ISO_FORTRAN_ENV` module, which requires Fortran 2003 or later.

Unit numbers 0, 5 and 6 will certainly work in the `ifort` compiler (and also in some other Fortran compilers), but keep in mind they are compiler-dependent.