# Differences when writing to / reading from the console between gfortran- and g77-compiled code

Tags: fortran, stdout, stdin, gfortran, g77

This one's going to take a bit of explaining.  Please bear with me.

## What I Have

I have in my possession some Fortran source code and some binaries that have been compiled from that code.  I did not do the compilation, but there is a build script that suggests G77 was used to do it.

As well as the Fortran stuff, there is also some Java code that provides users with a GUI "wrapper" around the binaries.  It passes information between itself and the binaries via their input/output/error pipes.  The Java code is very messy, and this way of doing things adds a lot of boilerplate and redundancy, but it does the job and I know it works.

## What I Need

Unfortunately, I'd like to make some changes:

1. I want to create a new Python wrapper for the binaries (or, more precisely, extend an existing Python program to become the new wrapper).
2. I want to be able to compile the Fortran code as part of this existing program's build process.  I would like to use gfortran for this, since MinGW is used elsewhere in the build and so it will be readily available.

## The Problem

When I compile the Fortran code myself using gfortran, I cannot get the resulting binaries to "talk" to either the current Java wrapper or my new Python wrapper.

Here are the various ways of printing to the console that I have tried in the Fortran code:

```
subroutine printA(message)
  write(6,*) message
end

subroutine printB(message)
  write(*,*) message
end

subroutine printC(message)
  use iso_fortran_env
  write(output_unit,*) message
end
```

There are also `read` commands as well, but the code doesn't even get a change to execute that part so I'm not worrying about it yet.

## Extra Info

- I have to call gfortran with the `-ffixed-line-length-132` flag so that the code compiles, but apart from that I don't use anything else.  I have tried using the `-ff2c` flag in the vague hope that it will make a difference.  It doesn't.
- This [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8508757/778572) is informative, but doesn't offer me anything that works.
- The [relavant manual page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GFORTRAN_005fSTDOUT_005fUNIT.html#GFORTRAN_005fSTDOUT_005fUNIT) suggests that printA should work just fine.
- I'm working on Windows, but will need this to be multi-platform.
- Juse in case you're intested, the Java code uses `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("prog.exe")` to call the binaries and then the various "stream" methods of the resulting `Process` object to communicate with them.  The Python code uses equivalents of this provided by the `Popen` object of the `subprocess` module.
- I should also say that I am aware there are alternatives.  Rewriting the code in Python (or something else like C++), or making amendments so that is it can be called via F2Py have been ruled out as options.  Using g77 is also a no-go; we have enough dependencies as it is.  I'd like to be able to write to / read from the console properly with gfortran, or know that it's just not possible.

Comment: for one thing, if message is charater type you need to declare it. its implicity integer as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing more details from your Fortran and Python codes. The following pair of code works for me (at least under Linux):

Fortran program repeating its input line by line prefixed with line number:

```
program test_communication
  use iso_fortran_env, stdout => output_unit, stdin => input_unit
  implicit none

  character(100) :: buffer
  integer :: ii

  ii = 1
  do while (.true.)
    read(stdin, *) buffer
    write(stdout, "(I0,A,A)") ii, "|", trim(buffer)
    flush(stdout)
    ii = ii + 1
  end do

end program test_communication
```

Python program invoking the Fortran binary. You can feed it with arbitrary strings from the console.

```
import subprocess as sub

print "Starting child"
proc = sub.Popen("./a.out", stdin=sub.PIPE, stdout=sub.PIPE)
while True:
    send = raw_input("Enter a string: ")
    if not send:
        print "Exiting loop"
        break
    proc.stdin.write(send)
    proc.stdin.write("\n")
    proc.stdin.flush()
    print "Sent:", send
    recv = proc.stdout.readline()
    print "Received:", recv.rstrip()
print "Killing child"
proc.kill()
```

Comment: This helps me inasmuch as it works when I compile it!  I'm not sure what exactly is different (maybe the flush statement) but it's enough to go on for now.  Many thanks.

Interestingly, I could get my code to work for a little while by setting the GFORTRAN_UNBUFFERED_ALL environment variable to 'y'.  It crashes very soon after that though.

Comment: Ok, "flush" was the key here.