# How to carriage return and flush in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, flush, carriage-return

I've always wondered about whether or not you can carriage return and flush a write statement in Fortran. In Python/C++ you can `'/r'` then flush the stream.

How can I do this in Fortran?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to flush stdout in Fortran 90?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471238/how-to-flush-stdout-in-fortran-90)

Comment: thanks for the referring question, I must've missed that. I've added a "call flush(6)" but how would use carriage return to make the flush command flushes the line and not just bits after what's already there?

Comment: `char(13)` is the ASCII carriage return. You can add this to the string you want to print. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/CHAR.html for details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A carriage-return is inserted by default at the end of a write statement, or explicitly using the ADVANCE specifier:

```
write(unit , '(A)') 'Hello World'
write(unit , '(A)' , ADVANCE = 'YES') 'Hello World'
write(unit , '(A)' , ADVANCE = 'YES') '-'
```

The result of the preceding three statements is:

```
Hello World
Hello World
-
```

Alternatively, the carriage-return may be suppressed by specifying ADVANCE='NO':

```
write(unit , '(A)' , ADVANCE = 'NO') 'Hello World'
write(unit , '(A)' , ADVANCE = 'NO') 'Hello World'
write(unit , '(A)' , ADVANCE = 'NO') '-'
```

Which yields:

```
Hello WorldHello World-
```

To flush in Fortran90, close the file and reopen.  Specific compilers and/or newer versions of the Fortran standard offer FLUSH as an intrinsic, but closing the file will always have the effect of flushing regardless of your Fortran version.