# Finding specific element in array with format specifier

Tags: arrays, matrix, fortran, fortran90

I am trying to extract a specific element in my matrix array that is in a text file and it doesn't seem to extract the element I want.
Here is the code I am using

```
real :: a

    open(unit=2,file='matrix.txt',status='old', form= 'formatted', action='read', &
        iostat=io_error)
      if ( io_error == 0) then

            read(2,100) a
            100 format(1x,2/,E8.1)
             write(*,*) 'a', a

       else
           write(*,*) 'unable to open file', &
                       io_error,' failed'
       end if

 close(unit=2)
```

Here are the values that I have

```
-1.000000e-001  -55.000000e+000 2
-2.000000e-001  -7.000000e-001  8
-3.000000e-001   0.000000e+000  5
-4.000000e-001   5.000000e-001  17
```

and I want to output the element in the 3rd row 2nd column.
Is this even possible?

But when I run the code I get -2.

Is there some other way that I can isolate an element when reading a from a file like this? And I would rather not have it read to a dummy variable.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Use tag [tag:fortran] for Fortran questions. Add a specific version tag if you need to distinguish. Don't use small unit numbers like your `2`, use numbers larger than 10 (you can also use `newunit=`).

Comment: Also see the edits are made so that you can write better questions next time.

Comment: What you mean by *"But when I run the code I get -2."*, is it an error or do you get `a  -2`?

Comment: thanks for responding vlad, why should you use larger unit numbers?

Comment: Because the small ones tend to be reserved for special purposes. Most often the 0,5 and 6 are pre-connected, but these numbers are not guaranteed, other small numbers can be taken as well.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508590/standard-input-and-output-units-in-fortran-90

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible, you just need a different format, you want to goet to the third row, than to the right column and read a real number with the right width.

```
open(newunit=iu, ,file='matrix.txt',status='old', form= 'formatted', action='read', &
        iostat=io_error)
...    
read(iu, '(2/,t16,e14.0)', iostat=io_error) a
```

This skips two records, shifts to column 16 and reads a real that is 14 characters wide. Check that the columns numbers are right. You always want `.0` with real numbers input, otherwise strange things can happen (treated in other Q/A here).

Instead of the `2/` you can execute two times `read(iu, *)`.

Instead of my `newunit=iu` and then `unit=iu` you can use a fixed number like `unit=11` for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a three pronged approach if you want to understand it

1) **reading**: the E8.1 might be correct, but it looks more like it should be a E8.5, or a 1PE12.5 but you do not need it.  also what happens on the read...? Is it the the first, second or third number that goes into the scalar a?

I have not compiled it, so it is just provided as conceptual example.

```
real :: a, b
Integer :: c

open(unit=22,file='matrix.txt',status='old', form= 'formatted', action='read', &
    iostat=io_error)
  if ( io_error == 0) then

        read(22,*) a, b, c
        100 format(1x,2/,E8.1)
         write(*,*) 'a=',a,' b=',b,' c=',c
   else
       write(*,*) 'unable to open file', &
                   io_error,' failed'
   end if

close(unit=22)
```

2) **Arrays**: you mentioned the third and second row/column.

```
real, dimension(3,100) :: a
Integer                :: I = 0

open(unit=22,file='matrix.txt',status='old', form= 'formatted', action='read', &
    iostat=io_error)
  if ( io_error == 0) then
        I = I + 1
        read(22,*) a(:, I)
        100 format(1x,2/,E8.1)
         write(*,*) 'a(:,',I,')', a(:, I)
   else
       write(*,*) 'unable to open file', &
                   io_error,' failed'
   end if

close(unit=22)
```

3) **Formats and Newunit**: Try Vladimir's new unit as well as formatted reads. (Usually I use I unformatted reads, and formatted writes)

Comment: E8.1 can't be right, the number is clearly wider. And you **really** always want `.0` on input.

Comment: I don't want to vote here, just show you how it works, because there appears to be some confusion here. It actually doesn't matter, whether you use `es`,`en`,`e` or `f` on input. Just the width is important. The `p` descriptor is tricky, better not play with it.

Comment: Hence the (,*) is what I prefer and a 1P12.5 on output, or an F15.3, or whatever.

Comment: When you write *Usually I use I unformatted reads* do you really mean *Usually I use I list-directed reads* ?  I ask because that is what you show in your code snippets and because in Fortran *unformatted* i/o is similar to what a lot of people call *binary* i/o.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark correct. List directed with no associated format statement. (clearly to us not an unformatted file, so best to clear that up).
Thanks.

Comment: So clear it up, your answer still contains a misleading suggestion.